# Can anyone recommend a lossless compression algo for compressing x and y coordinates?

Tags: compression, huffman-code, delta, lzw

I am needing some advice on a compression algo to compress x and y data coordinates. I am coding in Matlab. I have been doing quite a bit of research and came across Huffman Coding,LZW, Delta etc. What I can figure out from Huffman is, data needs to be sorted alphabetically prior to encoding?? This may be of no use to me as It would only work for x cordinates? Or is there a way around this? Any recommendations would be very appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should select the method based on the distribution of your numbers. Whats the precision o the numbers? What's the floor and ceiling value? Huffman is more suitable for distributions that have a lot of repetitions in a logarithmic begaviour, like for instance text. Deltas are better when having a lot of differences. 
First try to plot the data ina 2D plane and observe if there are any clusters appearing. You would need to give more information abuot it.